# position.top of a div changing constantly on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, offset, onscroll

i have to calculate the position().top of a series of divs inside of a self scrolling container.

the position is correctly calculated on load, but it constantly changes while scrolling.

here's a pen: https://codepen.io/frontend2020/pen/GRWJVvq (open the console to see the number changing on scroll)

i would need that initial number to never change, is this possible?

if I apply the same logic to `$(document).on("scroll", xxx);` instead of `$(".container").on("scroll", xxx);` that number never changes, and that's how I would want that to be in my case as well.

any hint or solution is greatly appreciated

Comment: But the position of your elements within your container does change on scroll. Just preserve the initial value in an array, json object or as a data attribute on each element on page load.

Comment: thanks @Lapskaus how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `offsetTop` instead of `position().top`; Here is the example codepen [link](https://codepen.io/prakash_m/pen/JjWYPEK)

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve the initial values, you could save them as data attributes on your divs on page load:

```js
function saveInitalTopValueAsDataAttribute() {
  $(".container div").each(function () {
    $(this).data('top', $(this).position().top);
  });  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    saveInitalTopValueAsDataAttribute();
});

$(".container").on("scroll", function() {
    $(this).find('div').each(function(){
      console.log( $(this).data('top') );
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container div {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
.container div:first-child {
  background: #000;
}
.container div:last-child {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```